# How to check for keywords in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, char, keyword-search

I'm trying to figure it out how to check some keywords in a string. This is the case. I'm getting a line from a file and i save it into a temp string. I have an array of strings with the type of keywords i'm looking for. For example, two keywords are begin and end, apart from a bunch of if statements to check every character, is there any other method to do it? 
My issues are the numbers of if and else that i'll get for every keyword i have, so i want a more efficient way of doing it
c++

Comment: "My issues are the numbers of if and else that i'll get for every keyword i have, so i want a more efficient way of doing it c++" -- open your C++ book to the chapter that teaches you how to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, and read this chapter.

Comment: Have you considered that showing us your code would help?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have never used map or unordered_map and i will check it, thanks you, but this is my goal in a big picture. from this string "begin int a = 0". I want to see if every word fits as a keyword or then i will save it as a identifier or a operator. So i need to check b then e, i g .... until i hit a whitespace or a delimitator. if it fits the keyword, i save it as a keyword, if not just as an identifier because at the end it's not like find of the string has the keyword, it's to check which word is

Comment: This approach is wrong. That's not how tokenizers, or parsers of this kind, typically work. Parsing input of non-trivial structure is actually a fairly involved process; and the traditional solution employs a [lexical analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). This is college-level computer science, and, as such, is not really something that can be described in a few paragraphs on stackoverflow.com, especially to someone who does not have the requisite background knowledge.

Comment: I'm a college student, and it's a compiler design class. We are making a program that simulates a lexical analizer that is reading an input file that is a code and then show the code in the screen as a stream of tokens. <OPTk, 1> We are simulating the analyzer, that's why we are not storing tokens as it should be. I was trying to find a way to check the characters in the string to test it and then go in deep into the main purpose. Just finding an algorithm or a syntax for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string input{"apple double banana int float chimpanzee"};
    std::vector<std::string> keywords{"double", "int", "float", "switch"};

    for(const auto& keyword : keywords)
    {
        auto pos = input.find(keyword);

        std::cout << keyword
            << " [" << (pos == std::string::npos ? " not found" : " found") << "]\n";   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `O(n)`. given the stated desire for a "more efficient way", and the fact that there are trivial solutions in C++ that can accomplish this with logarithmic complexity, rather than linear one, means that this is not the best answer.